# How to share state between different environments via terragrunt?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Suppose I have defined two environments - staging and production via terragrunt. Each uses common module definitions and parametrizes them by environment. This all makes sense until I want to configure gitlab and inject things like ECR repo URLs into gitlab's CI/CD variables. I've attempted to create a common bucket in a root account and given access to it to each of the roles, but there seems to be no way of overriding the remote_state setting via terragrunt.hcl.

What is the right way of doing this?